# ExtJS4: stop event bubbling with Ext.draw

Tags: extjs, raphael, extjs4

I'm having some difficulties with event bubbling with ExtJS4 and its drawing components:

```
drawComponent.on('click', function(){
    var sprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
        type: 'circle',
        fill: '#79BB3F',
        stroke: '#000000',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        radius: 100,
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        surface: this.surface,
        listeners: {
            'click': function(el,e){
                console.log('clicked');
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    });
    sprite.show(true);
});
```

When clicking the `drawComponent`, a circle is drawn. When clicking the circle, this should only trigger the `clickHandler` of the circle, not the `drawComponent`.

Any idea what could be wrong with my code? `e.stopPropagation()` should stop the event bubble.

Thanks,
Chielus

Comment: if you stick a `console.log` in your `drawComponent` click event, which one fires first?

Comment: drawComponent is fired first... so event bubbling isn't the problem... any idea what is?

Comment: looks like it's the architecture of ExtJS that is the problem. Do you only want the `sprite` to be created once?

Comment: It's probably a bug in ExtJS4, since this is a new version (4.0.0). Unless I'm doing something wrong, it looks ok to me though...

Comment: Is the sprite meant to be created once only?

Comment: nope, what I want is this:
1) click on the drawComponent (or its surface): draw a circle.
2) click on the circle: do something with the circle (eg. highlight it).

So if i click 3 times on the surface, 3 circles would be drawn.

Comment: Hmm, i would file a bug report over at sencha.com/forum and see what they say. The event should bubble, but it would involve rewriting the code for draw component in Ext to fix the issue

Comment: I already have: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133592-event-on-sprite-fires-also-an-event-on-drawComponent&p=602523#post602523. No answer yet though... community of Sencha can be better

Answer (score 0):

Use the `addManagedListeners` method rather than the `listeners` property to add the click event.

The `click` event on the component should be removed as well.

**References**

- [Ext.draw.Sprite](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite)